# Unable to connect to docker container in Jenkins pipeline when using "Docker outside of Docker" setup

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, cypress, docker-in-docker

I'm running a Jenkins job based on such agent:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'cypress/base:10'
        args '-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker -v /usr/local/bin/docker-compose:/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -u root'
    }
  }
…
```

**note:** `docker` and `docker-compose` are mounted into my agent container to be able to run docker containers inside the pipeline stages ("Docker outside of Docker" setup)

down the pipeline, I start `docker-compose` setup that consists of 2 containers - server and webapp

```
…
sh 'docker-compose up --build --detach'
…
```

After that, I want to send a GET request to `localhost:8080`, this is where the web-app should be served from. But I get

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED localhost:8080
```

The same docker-compose setup works on my dev. machine. Port forwarding is set up correctly (8080:8080 port forwarding is enabled in `docker-compose` configuration file)

I think it's somewhat related to the "Docker outside of Docker" setup that I do in Jenkins Maybe port 8080 actually appears to be listening on the host of the agent of my pipeline, not sure…

I will be happy to get fresh ideas on the problem, completely run out of my mind with this.

*And just to give more context: I want to run web-app + API server via docker-compose and then run Cypress (outside of docker-compose setup) to do E2E testing via UI*

Comment: Run lsof -i:8080 and check if any other process is using that port

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins docker out of docker setup, technically, Jenkins is also another container that "shares" the same space with other containers. Meaning, it can communicate to the containers it "created".

In my case, what I did was create a custom bridge network on my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    depends_on:
      - redisdb
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

  redisdb:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:6380:6379
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  frontend: {}
  backend: {}
```

Then once this is created, docker-compose creates these networks with the following format:

- {FOLDER_NAME}_frontend (example: pipeline_frontend)
- {FOLDER_NAME}_backend

These networks are usually bridge networks.

My Jenkins container originally resides in the default network "bridge". Since my jenkins is in a bridge network and these containers are in a bridge type network, I can connect my jenkins via runtime later in the pipeline.

```
docker network connect pipeline_frontend jenkins
```

Now from jenkins, I can communicate directly to the container via its service name.
In my case for example, from my Jenkins, I can curl to http://app:8080

**Note:** This answer is only applicable if Jenkins container exclusively resides in the host as with the containers it creates. I have not tested this on a setup wherein Jenkins has external nodes.